# Update CoreDNS config via configmap

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, coredns

Using Kubernetes, I'm trying to map *.api requests to *.
[I found this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54509142/coredns-suffix-rewrite-causes-dns-queries-to-return-the-rewritten-name) which helps me how to achieve this and it's working by updating the CoreDNS configuration.
But I would like to do this via a yaml apply so it can be easily deployed to different environments. Also if the CoreDNS config changes in a later release, I won't be getting those changes.
So my question is, how could I apply a yaml file to achieve this:

```
rewrite stop {
    name regex (.*)\.api {1}.some-namespace.svc.cluster.local
    answer name (.*)\.some-namespace\.svc\.cluster\.local {1}.api
}
```

I found this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/coredns-custom
But I'm unable to figure out how I can use that example for my use-case.

Answer (score 2):

Given that there are no other answers yet, let me describe a possible approach...two, actually.

The main idea is to use CoreDNS' [import](https://coredns.io/plugins/import/) directive - "...The import plugin can be used to include files into the main configuration". And from the CoreDNS manual - "...This plugin is a bit special in that it may be used anywhere in the Corefile".

One option (#1) is to edit the `coredns` configMap to add `import` directive to include configuration from another file like in these configMap-s for [AKS](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/v0.42.2/parts/k8s/addons/coredns.yaml#L62) and [k3s](https://github.com/rancher/k3s/blob/60801e215316c95dd4e65e0203556376a2ca6dd1/manifests/coredns.yaml#L58); then add a new volume in the deployment config - see [here](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/v0.42.2/parts/k8s/addons/coredns.yaml#L171-L173) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/v0.42.2/parts/k8s/addons/coredns.yaml#L214-L220).

Another option (#2) could be to add a new configMap with your configuration and that also imports the `/etc/coredns/Corefile` file mounted as volume from the "stock" `coredns` configMap; change the `coredns` *deployment* configuration to add a volume from the new configMap and point the ["-conf" argument](https://github.com/Azure/aks-engine/blob/v0.42.2/parts/k8s/addons/coredns.yaml#L166) to the file mounted as volume from the new configMap.

A drawback is that in both cases you'll have to re-implement the change if in a later release the coredns configMap and/or deployment configuration change.

Comment: Thanks. It sounds like it would be much less trouble to just go with the flow and lose the .api part of the URLs I'm using inside my applications ;-)